# Building shadow jar with gradle locally

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

I am using [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin in gradle to build jar file, I have added the build script as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.2'
    }
}
```

Instead of asking `gradle` to fetch shadow-1.2.2.jar from `jcenter()`, I want to get the `shadow-1.2.2.jar` from http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/1.2.2/

I just want to build it locally, I have put the `shadow-1.2.2.jar` in libs folder and my build script is

```
buildscript {
    //repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.2'
    }
}
```

But it not working please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code should work:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

There's no `compile` configuration for gradle `buildscript` dependencies.